# Ionic Login (AngularJS) + localstorage issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a compatibility issue between ionic framework and localstorage cordova,
indeed when i get my localstorage in my input text login my application don't detect that we have some text in the input.

But if i click on the input delete one letter and type one letter my controller detect the text.

Please someone can help me?

HTML:

```
    <form name="form" class="padding">               
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input ng-model="login.username" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Utilisateur" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input ng-model="login.password" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Mot De Passe" required>
            </label>
            <div class="padding">
                <button class="button button-block button-outline button-assertive" ng-click="login()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Se Connecter</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller.js

```
 $scope.login = function (username, password) {

    Chats.login($scope.login).then(function (data) {

        if (Object.keys(data.data).length === 1) {

            window.localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.login.username);
            window.localStorage.setItem("password", $scope.login.password);
            console.log($scope.login.password);

            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({

                disableBack: true
            });

            $state.go('app.accueil');

        } else {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "Erreur",
                template: "Verifiez Utilisateur et Mot De Passe",
                okText: 'Ok',
                okType: 'button-positive'
            });
        }
    })
}
```

app.js

```
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

    document.getElementById('username').value = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
    document.getElementById('password').value = window.localStorage.getItem("password");
```

Comment: can you replicate this in a plunker or fiddle

Comment: What do you mean with "my application don't detect that we have some text in the input"? What part of your code is not detecting the changes? Is an if statement failing?

Comment: if i type my login and password on keyboard i have not issue. but when i get the data by localstorage ondeviceready my input text don't detect that something is typed

Comment: It might be a type problem, what type(string, number) did you initialize these variables(login.username/login.password)? There is some code missing.

Comment: at my first login i save my username and password with setitem. and next time i open my app i get the username and password in my input text with getitem but i can't click on the login button cause my app don't detect the text in the input.

Comment: i edited with the app.js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the scope to assign the saved values to the input-fields:

```
$scope.login.username = window.localStorage.getItem("username") ? window.localStorage.getItem("username") : "";
$scope.login.password = window.localStorage.getItem("password") ? window.localStorage.getItem("password") : "";
```

And if I were you I would check whether these values are always strings:

```
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("username")); // => "Username"
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("password")); // => "Password"
```

Otherwise there might be problems as well.